# Why SageMaker endpoints are not public

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

After exploring many articles, I found that the SageMaker endpoints can only be accessed using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda functions.

The document for SageMaker endpoint also states the following:

> Endpoints are scoped to an individual account, and are not public. The URL does not contain the account ID, but Amazon SageMaker determines the account ID from the authentication token that is supplied by the caller.

I would like to know the standard way and best practices to make the SageMaker endpoints available through REST API's preferably with Python 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial explains very well how to nest a SageMaker endpoint behind API Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/